# Is it possible to document a javascript plain object using ESDOC?

Tags: javascript, documentation, esdoc

It seems that ESDOC targets only ES6 class style.

Is there a way to document a plain object like:

```
/**
 * ???
 */
var Foo = {
    /**
     * ???
     */
    info: true
};

export default Foo;
```

And even when using ES6 class style, how to document a static property like:

```
class Bar {
}

/**
 * ???
 */
Bar.info = true;

export default Bar;
```

Answer (score 5):

Short answer. No.

ESDOC is designed specifically to document ES6 classes. It's right in the name. From the [FAQ](https://doc.esdoc.org/github.com/esdoc/esdoc/manual/faq/faq.html):

> ESDoc supports ES2015 and later

If you need to document a mixture of ES6+ and regular (prototypal) classes, [JSDOC](http://usejsdoc.org/index.html) might be a better bet. It's fairly mature and it's format is a sort of defacto standard.

If you don't like or can't use the main JSDOC package, there are plenty of other options. Just for example, I've had success with [jsdoc-to-markdown](https://github.com/jsdoc2md/jsdoc-to-markdown) on my projects. You should be able to find the tools to convert JSDOC to whatever format you need.

Answer (score 1):

For member and variable you should use [@type](https://esdoc.org/manual/usage/tags.html#-type)

```
/**
* @type {Object}
* @property {boolean} Foo.info describe Foo.info
*/
const Foo = {
   info: true
};
```

and for static properties in es6 you should use [className.method_member](https://esdoc.org/manual/usage/tags.html#identifier-syntax)

```
/**
* This is Bar description.
*/
class Bar {
  /**
  * Bar.info
  */
  static info=true
}
```

check esdoc output [here](https://try.esdoc.org/#indexCode=%23%20Welcome%20to%20ESDoc%0A%0AThis%20is%20the%20place%20to%20try%20ESDoc.%20Please%20write%20a%20code%20and%20click%20%60Try%20it%20out%60!%0A%0A-%20%60Index%60%20(this)%20is%20used%20as%20a%20index%20page(Markdown).%0A-%20%60Source%20Code%60%20is%20used%20as%20a%20source%20code(JavaScript)%0A-%20%60Test%20Code%60%20is%20used%20as%20a%20test%20code(JavaScript).%0A-%20%60Manual(Usage)%60%20is%20used%20as%20a%20manual%20of%20usage(Markdown).%0A-%20%60Config%60%20is%20used%20as%20a%20configuration(JSON).%0A&sourceCode=%2F**%0A%20*%20%40type%20%7BObject%7D%0A%20*%20%40property%20%7Bboolean%7D%20Foo.info%20describe%20Foo.info%0A%20*%2F%0A%20const%20Foo%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20info%3A%20true%0A%20%7D%3B%0A%0A%0A%2F**%0A*%20This%20is%20Bar%20description.%0A*%2F%0Aclass%20Bar%20%7B%0A%20%20%2F**%0A%20%20*%20Bar.info%0A%20%20*%2F%0A%20%20static%20info%3Dtrue%0A%7D&testCode=%2F**%0A%20*%20this%20is%20test%20for%20MyClass.%0A%20*%20%40test%20%7BMyClass%7D%0A%20*%2F%0Adescribe('test%20MyClass'%2C%20()%3D%3E%7B%0A%20%20%2F**%0A%20%20%20*%20this%20is%20test%20for%20MyClass%23method.%0A%20%20%20*%20%40test%20%7BMyClass%23method%7D%0A%20%20%20*%2F%0A%20%20it('has%20a%20method'%2C%20()%3D%3E%7B%0A%20%20%20%20assert(new%20MyClass(100).method)%3B%0A%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%7D)%3B%0A&manualCode=%23%20Usage%0A%0AThis%20is%20usage%20for%20MyModule%20that%20is%20written%20by%20GitHub%20Flavored%20Markdown.%0A%0A-%20this%20is%20list%20item1%0A-%20this%20is%20list%20item2%0A-%20this%20is%20list%20item3%0A%0A%60%60%60js%0Aconst%20myClass%20%3D%20new%20MyClass(100)%3B%0Aconst%20hello%20%3D%20myClass.method(1%2C%202)%3B%0Aconsole.log(hello)%3B%0A%60%60%60%0A&configCode=%7B%0A%20%20%22source%22%3A%20%22__SOURCE__%22%2C%0A%20%20%22destination%22%3A%20%22__DESTINATION__%22%2C%0A%20%20%22access%22%3A%20%5B%22public%22%2C%20%22protected%22%2C%20%22private%22%5D%2C%0A%20%20%22unexportIdentifier%22%3A%20true%2C%0A%20%20%22undocumentIdentifier%22%3A%20true%2C%0A%20%20%22index%22%3A%20%22__INDEX__%22%2C%0A%20%20%22experimentalProposal%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22classProperties%22%3A%20true%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22objectRestSpread%22%3A%20true%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22decorators%22%3A%20true%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22doExpressions%22%3A%20true%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22functionBind%22%3A%20true%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22asyncGenerators%22%3A%20true%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22exportExtensions%22%3A%20true%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22dynamicImport%22%3A%20true%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%22test%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22type%22%3A%20%22mocha%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22source%22%3A%20%22__TEST__%22%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%22manual%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22usage%22%3A%20%5B%22__MANUAL__%22%5D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A)

Comment: This does not work for method properties, they are not generated properly in the documentation

Comment: for method parameters you should use @param

Comment: I know, but the documentation doesnt generate correctly. It doesnt decribe the function

Comment: I have added output, is it OK?